# Opening many filestreams

Tags: c++, filestream

If I run the following program, only 509 files are created. In fact, I don't seem to be able to have more than 509 filestreams open at a time. If I delete `file` inside the loop, all 1000 files are created. Is there any way to have more than 509 filestreams open at a time? I'm running Windows.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        std::ofstream *file = new std::ofstream("files/"+i+".txt");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have 1000 files open at a time?

Comment: nighthawk's link say that 512 is the limit (although this can be changed). This fits with your value of 509 since there's also the 3 standard streams.

Comment: All right! Sorry for not finding that question myself. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @nighthawk702 Please post an answer, so people know this question is dealt with. You could get points, too :)